# How can i get the XML values in mule?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el, mule-module-jpa

In Mule I am using SOAP Component it is receiving the WSDL file in XML format. After that I want to get The XML data. but it show error. Here i am using

```
#[message.InboundProperties['Subject']]
```

It show the Null Value. This my XML Code

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:out="http://soap.sforce.com/2005/09/outbound" xmlns:urn="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <out:notifications>
         <out:OrganizationId>00D9XXXXXXXXXXXx</out:OrganizationId>
         <out:ActionId>04k90xxxxxx</out:ActionId>
         <out:SessionId>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</out:SessionId>
         <out:EnterpriseUrl>https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/29.0/00D90000000q0Mc</out:EnterpriseUrl>
         <out:PartnerUrl>https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/29.0/00D90000000q0Mc</out:PartnerUrl>
         <!--1 to 100 repetitions:-->
         <out:Notification>
            **<out:Id>?</out:Id>
            <out:sObject>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <urn:fieldsToNull>?</urn:fieldsToNull>
                <!--Optional:-->
               <urn:Subject>Test</urn:Subject>
            </out:sObject>**
         </out:Notification>
      </out:notifications>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

SOAP Working properly.  `<urn:Subject>Test</urn:Subject>` the Subject value from this XML file

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question:

Are you getting an error trying to run your program or when you call from SOAP client?
Can you paste your Mule code.
If you want to have the XML as your payload after the SOAP message processor(MP) you will need to set the operation to 'proxy service' inside the SOAP MP.

Comment: Now Flow is working fine. for receiving the XML nodes i am using XPATH
 <logger message="#[xpath('//*[local-name()=\'Description\']').text]&quot;" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
But its support only LocalSystem how can i use the Online. It show the error on online working time.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by LocalSystem - mule Studio?
Can you add the error for me?

Comment: localhost:8081 this address working for xpath. but its not working for URL. okay Can you tell me how can i retrive the xml nodes value. already i paste my xml code format based on this format i should receive the value by using XPATH. how can i?

Answer (score 0):

Since the XML is a SOAP, to extract a node value you need to use XPATH http://blogs.mulesoft.com/mule-3-6-xml-xpath-xslt-xquery3/
and Mule namespace maneger
https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/XML+Namespaces